# Avoiding Repetition in Logic

Tags: conditional-statements

I am trying to find a better way of programming the following:

```
if (amount == "all") {
   if (type == "labs") {
    //get lab info
   } else if (type == "trolleys") {
    //get trolley info
   } else if (type == "all") {
    //get both lab and trolley info
   }
}
```

I am not using any functions to get that information as it is just a few lines of codes but I do not want to repeat the get lab and get trolley in the get all.

Have I answered my own question and I should just use a function or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle both cases in the same conditionals:

```
if (amount == "all") {
  if (type == "labs" || type == "all") {
    // labs
  }

  if (type == "trolleys" || type == "all") {
    // trolleys
  }
```

}